# How to copy files in S3 from folder to another recursively using bash script?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, for-loop, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have a folder structure like this in my AWS S3 bucket named myfiles:

```
mainfolder/
|-- current
`-- error
    `-- files
        |-- files1
        `-- files2
```

I'm trying to copy all the files under files1 and files2 folders to current, so that resulting structure shows like this:

```
mainfolder/
|-- current
|   |-- files1
|   `-- files2
`-- error
    `-- files
        |-- files1
        `-- files2
```

I'm trying to do this using simple bash for loop like:

```
BUCKET=myfiles
for dir in $(aws s3 ls s3://$BUCKET/mainfolder/error/files/ | awk '{print $2}'); do
    aws s3 cp $i s3://$BUCKET/mainfolder/current/$i
done
```

but I'm getting errors:

```
The user-provided path 0 does not exist.
```

How this could be done?

Comment: Try aws s3 sync s3://bkt/mainfolder/error/files/ s3://bkt/mainfolder/current/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
aws s3 sync s3://my-bucket/mainfolder/error/files/ s3://my-bucket/mainfolder/current/
```

or:

```
aws s3 cp --recursive s3://my-bucket/mainfolder/error/files/* s3://my-bucket/mainfolder/current/
```

See: [sync — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)